# .Net Core XmlDocument doesn't return declaration

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, .net-core, xmldocument

I have a .net core web application with a XmlDocument, this doesn't return declaration, even without modifications.

I have this code

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/xml")]
[Produces("application/xml")]
public ActionResult<XmlDocument> GW1()
{
    XmlDocument xmlDocRec = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocRec.Load(Request.Body);
    return Ok(xmlDocRec);
}
```

Request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GR User="User1" PropertyCode="90001045">
    <GW>1</GW>
</GR>
```

Response

```
<GR User="User1" PropertyCode="90001045">
    <GW>1</GW>
</GR>
```

I have this in Startup

```
services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
                .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

I need in response `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` but i don't know why it doesn't not return. In xmlDocRec.InnerXml and xmlDocRec.OuterXml exists.

I haven't class as parameters and response neither, i can't use it for requirement, for that i use Request.Body

Obviously i work with xmlDocRec, i add and update elements, but result is the same. When i work with xmlDocRec, xmlDocRec.InnerXml and xmlDocRec.OuterXml contains `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>`. Later, i will need to delete standalone="no" because it must not be in response.

--- Edit

I don't know if it is rigth way, but for now i'm using this

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult GW1()
{
    XmlDocument xmlDocRec = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocRec.Load(Request.Body);

    return new ContentResult
    {
        ContentType = "application/xml",
        Content = xmlDocRec.OuterXml,
        StatusCode = 200
    };
}
```

With that, i don't need Consumes, Produces and AddXmlSerializerFormatters in startup.

If some know a better way I'm willing to try.

Comment: Is it a requirement to use XmlDocument? What about XDocument?

Comment: Yes, i need use XmlDocument

Answer (score 3):

You could try to configure your XmlSerializerOutputFormatter in the ConfigureServices method using XmlWriterSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration and setting it to false as this is set to true by default.

```
private void ConfigureXmlOutpuFormatter(MvcOptions options)
{
     XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
     {
       OmitXmlDeclaration = false
     };
     options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter(settings));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to craft your response with explicit property values set on the `XmlDeclaration` class.

> I suggest you take a look at the [XmlDeclaration Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldeclaration?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("application/xml")]
[Produces("application/xml")]
public ActionResult<XmlDocument> EchoXmlAndChangeEncoding()
{
    string requestXML = Request.Body;

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(new StringReader(requestXML));

    // Grab the XML declaration. 
    XmlDeclaration xmldecl = doc.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlDeclaration>().FirstOrDefault();
    xmldecl.Encoding = "UTF-8";
    xmldecl.Standalone = null;   // <-- or do whatever you need

    ... // set other declarations here

    // Output the modified XML document 
    return Ok(doc.OuterXml);
}
```

Comment: I had read that post, but it need ´XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
    doc.InsertBefore(xmldecl, root);´ but with that throw a error, Cannot insert the node in the specified location. Because exits, InnerXml and OuterXml show it but return does'n't

Comment: @M.Mis -- given that you needed a more clear answer (rather than a hint) I have updated my answer to show the entire method for you.

Comment: Thank, but nothing change, even string requestXML = Request.Body throw error. doc.OuterXml return a string with declaration, not a xml but, how my original question says, my code with OuterXml return declaration too. I guess, my problem is with configuration but i don't know what i miss